# Did Galen make any theoretical contributions to the experimental science?

Tags: biographical-details, philosophy-of-science, medicine

The wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_experiments) about experimental research history cites Ibn al-Haytham as an early pioneer of experimental research.
Since Galen was the last prominent ancient greek philosophers/doctor and according to his wikipedia page he conducted some [medical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galen) demonstrations/experiments on animals I am wondering if he philosophized on the theoretical aspects of his demonstrations.

Comment: *experiment* is a modern scientific "technique". Ancient science was based on *observation*.

Comment: The "theory" of experiment is due to Francis Bacon; the first modern significant example are William Harvey and Galileo.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Although his wikipedia page names his demonstrations experiments I agree with you that the notion of experiment is a relatively modern one. Maybe he phrased some of the theoretical aspects on how he made his demonstrations/observations in a novel way that aided early pioneers of the (proto) experimental method to formulate their own theories on "experimentation".

Comment: Unlike optics, medicine does not lend itself well to experimenting even today: there are too many factors, the subjects are live and can't be freely obtained or manipulated, patterns are obscure and hard to quantify. Galen's approach was broadly Aristotelian, loose observations combined with *a priori* speculations, see [Galen’s Critical Empiricism](https://www.iep.utm.edu/galen/#H4). Neither of them was a theoretician of experiments, on this front Alhazen got more from [Ptolemy's Optics](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-009-2875-6_11).

Comment: @Conifold I agree with you that "medicine may not lend itself well to experimenting" generally but according to wikipedia Galen did some non trivial "experiments". It seems to me that there were/are some low hanging fruits in medical research .The article that you cite about Galen is not very exhaustive.